# Need to find files where the file is named for a API generated serial number + YYYYMMDD

Tags: bash, date, find

I need to find files named with a API generated serial number + YYYYMMDD followed API time stamp data.

Examples:

```
send0167663112011110414150180.xml --Created 20111104
send0148402292010121812300296.xml --Created 20101218
send0152858682009032013000173.xml --Created 20090320
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which language you are trying this on.
If you are using c#, use DirectoryInfo.GetFiles on the directory of interest and get the file info of the files inside the directory using 'FileInfo' and check for 'Name' and compare with what you want.

Comment: Doh.  My Apologies.  Bash.  I also neglected to mention that the serial number prepends the date is the same for all files.

Comment: This accomplishes my goal.  find -type -f -mtime +142 -exec ls -ltr {} \;  I am still interested in how one might parse the file name and only return files having the desired YYYYMMDD in the name.

Comment: "I am still interested ...", then you need to update your question with more specifics (and not reply via comments :-)). Will the date always appear starting at N chars from left (or right, for that matter)?  Also, you can post your own answer and accept in 24 hrs, gaining additional rep-points. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This will find files that end with the date and meet the other criteria.

```
date=20111104
find -type -f -name "*$date" -mtime +142 -exec ls -ltr {} \;
```